# C# nested if-else optimization with almost similar values

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, optimization, nested

I have new user data (i want to import/update it). Accounts is finded by user data.
I want to update or create new accounts depended on finded accounts by user data
:

```
            if (accountById != null)
            {
                if (accountByNumber != null)
                {
                    if (accountById.Id == accountByNumber.Id)
                    {
                        if (_isSpecialData)
                        {
                            AddUserDataToAccount(userData, accountByNumber);

                            if (userData.Status == Blocked) return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _log.Error($"Bad");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    AddUserDataToAccount(userData, accountById);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (accountByNumber != null)
                {
                    if (accountByNumber.RefNo == null)
                    {                            
                        SetAccountAdditionalId(accountByNumber, userData.AdditionalId);

                        if (_isSpecialData)
                        {
                            AddUserDataToAccount(userData, accountByNumber);
                            if (userData.Status == Blocked) return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _log.Error($"Bad");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    CreateCardAndProfile2(userData, out createdNewAccount);
                    CreateNewAccount(userData, out createdNewAccount);
                }
            }
                        
            UpdateAccountData(userData, createdNewAccount);
```

The above method works, but I would like to know if there is any way to make it more readable, optimized?

Comment: Questions like theese are off topic for Stack Overflow. Post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Thank you @MathewHD, I do not know about this website.
I posted here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249680/c-nested-if-else-optimization-with-almost-similar-values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch operator so you can remove a lot of the if statements. if works like this:
(Note: Make sure you have a default case and a break; at the end of every case)

```
switch(%a%variable%here%) {

    case %variable%value& {

        %code%here%;
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't see, how a switch statement should help in this case.